# How to clean up eventListener using event subscription from useEffect?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const myFn = () => {
      // do something
    };

    AppState.addEventListener('change', myFn);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', myFn);
    };
  }, []);
```

which will remove event listener on unmount.

However, with latest react-native, `removeEventListener('type', ...)` is deprecated, with the message `Use the 'remove()' method on the event subscription returned by 'addEventListener()'.`

How can you do this? Do you use a ref to store the event subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation for [`removeEventListener()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener):

> ### `removeEventListener()`
>
> ```ts
> removeEventListener(eventType, listener);
> ```
>
> > Deprecated. Use the `remove()` method on the `EventSubscription` returned by [`addEventListener()`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#addeventlistener).

Using the new pattern with the example code that you showed would look like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const myFn = () => {
    // do something
  };

  const eventSubscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', myFn);

  return () => eventSubscription.remove();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

As [per the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener), what they are wanting you to do is save the output of `addEventListener` which will have its own `remove` method instead of referencing the `myFn` handler:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const myFn = () => {
      // do something
    };

    const event = AppState.addEventListener('change', myFn);

    return () => {
      event.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: It's ok to copy information from other answers, as long as you indicate that you did so. If that's not the case here, and you did your own research to discover the documentation link that you included in your [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74047921/2), then — in the future — consider waiting to post your answer until after it's in a completed state.

Comment: you can see i answered the question before there was another answer posted in the edit history. Dont really know how i would have gotten the info without reading the docs.. As this is not a race, i normally edit after posting the code of my answer so other people dont end up saying the same thing.. as you did. Seeing you say the same thing i decided to upvote your answer instead of claiming you stole it

Comment: Thank you both :) I accepted the other answer since it's worded *slightly* clearer, but thank you both for your help!